# DLL load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets error in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qwebengineview

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\pythoncodes\DGA\Article1\from PyQt6.py", line 1, in <module>
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets: The specified procedure could
```

when running this code:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
```

How can I solve this?

I should use PyQt6 in this code.

Comment: Please provide more details: are you getting that error when using an IDE (if so, which one?) or when running it normally? How did you install PyQt6? How did you install (if you did install it) PyQt-WebEngine?

Comment: The stack trace was cut off. Provide the environment variables, especially the ```PATH```. I suspect you have another QT installation other than the one embedded the PyQt6 package.